# Active link works on page refresh but not scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my links in my fixed header to change on scroll.

The code seems to work if you refresh the page for e.g. If you scroll to Section C and refresh the page and scroll it recognises you're on that section, but for some reason it doesn't seem to do it dynamically whilst scrolling.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lr53c1oh/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        nav {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background: #f5f5f5;
            text-align: center;
        }

        nav ul {
            list-style: none;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }

        section {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 8rem;
            color: #fff;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .sectionA {
            background: orangered;
        }
        .sectionB {
            background: steelblue;
        }
        .sectionC {
            background: purple;
        }
        .sectionD {
            background: black;
        }

        .active {
            color: red;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="sectionA-marker">Section A</li>
            <li class="sectionB-marker">Section B</li>
            <li class="sectionC-marker">Section C</li>
            <li class="sectionD-marker">Section D</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="sectionA">
        <h2>Section A</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="sectionB">
        <h2>Section B</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="sectionC">
        <h2>Section C</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="sectionD">
        <h2>Section D</h2>
    </section>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var navHeight = $("nav").height();
    var sectionElement = $("section");

    $(document).on("scroll", function(){
        sectionElement.each(function(){
            var section = $(this);

            if( section.offset().top < (scrollTop + navHeight) && (scrollTop + navHeight) < (section.offset().top + section.outerHeight()) ) {
                var targetClass = "." + section.attr("class") + "-marker";
                $("nav ul li").removeClass("active");
                $(targetClass).addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
}());

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the corrected fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Lr53c1oh/3/

you need to get the current value of scrollTop every time in the scroll event

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
//rest of the code
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edited**

Sorry, my first answer was pretty lazy;

You issue happens because you trying to compare each section top's not with current position of screen, but the position you get when page loaded.

So the event should be like:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
    // get new value of scrollTop after each event call
    scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

    sectionElement.each(function(){
        var section = $(this);

        if( section.offset().top < (scrollTop + navHeight) && (scrollTop + navHeight) < (section.offset().top + section.outerHeight()) ) {
            var targetClass = "." + section.attr("class") + "-marker";
            $("nav ul li").removeClass("active");
            $(targetClass).addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'd like to be able to do it on my own also :)